# Extract image from PDF using PHP

Tags: php, image, pdf, ocr

I already used [pdfimages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html) and it's working but when i tried to upload it on hosting, it's not working because exec, shell_exec, passthru and system function is disable. I can't enable it because it can hack my website.

I found a library called nusoap. I can extract image but it will only extract when images have effects like shadow, glow, reflection, etc.

Can anyone help me to find a library or code PHP to extract image from PDF? I start doing it one month ago and I'm still not finish on it. Sadlife.

Comment: i would move to a decent host (one that does not disable the Program execution Functions)

Comment: @Dagon do you know the popen function? it's like exec function right? I tried to used it to run pdfimages, it's working in localhost but when I tried to upload it on hosting, it's not working

Comment: if your hosts disable exec, they would probably disable popen as well

Comment: @Dagon maybe but I saw the phpinfo in host. The only disabled function are system, shell_exec, passthru and exec. It's okay to enable exec? because I read from some website that It can hack your website when exec, system, etc. is enabled.